# Getting rid of bullet points from <ul>

Tags: html, html-lists

I have the following list:

```
 <ul id="otis">
 <li>Benz</li>
 <li>Other Benz</li>
 <li>Other Other Benz</li>
 </ul>
```

I want to get rid the bullets so i tried:

```
 ul#otis {
 list-style-type: none;
 }
```

That didn't work though. What is the proper way to remove the bullets from the displayed list?

Comment: Your current HTML/CSS works fine for me in FF (JSFiddle). Which browser are you using? See if `list-style: none` works instead.

Comment: i tried this on all browsers and mac and windows OS. i am using html5 doctype...

Answer (score 240):

Assuming that didn't work, you might want to combine the `id`-based selector with the `li` in order to apply the css to the `li` elements:

```
#otis li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Reference:

- [`list-style-type` at the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type).

Comment: What is the difference of doing `ul#otis` and `#otis`?

Comment: Actually there isn't one, I, um, just completely failed to see the `id` selector that you used. Oops...sorry!

Comment: where on that link can I find that it needs to be defined on the `li`?

Comment: The first two sentences: "The `list-style-type` CSS property specifies appearance of a list item element. As it is the only one who defaults to `display:list-item`" (although it does allow that it *can* apply to any element with a `display` property). Although they do define it, for their example, under the `ol` element. Personally I always default to defining it for both the list (`ul`/`ol`) *and* the `li` elements.

Answer (score 29):

I had the same extreme irritating problem myself since the script did not take any notice of my styelsheet.
So I wrote:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
```

That did not work. So, **in addition**, I wrote:

```
<li style="list-style-type: none;">
```

Voila! it worked!

Answer (score 25):

The following code

```css
#menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Root node 1</li>
    <li>Root node 2</li>
</ul>
```

will produce this output:

[image: output is]

Answer (score 21):

To remove bullet points from unordered lists , you can use:

```
list-style: none;
```

You can also use:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Either works but the first is a shorter way to get the same result.

Answer (score 15):

Try this instead, tested on Chrome/Safari

```
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove bullet from **`UL`** you can simply use **`list-style: none;`** or **`list-style-type: none;`** If still not works then i guess there is an issue of priority **CSS**. May be globally UL already defined. So best way add a class/ID to that particular UL and add your **CSS** there. Hope it will works.

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
<style type="text/css">
 ul#otis {
     list-style-type: none;
   }
</style>
```

immediately before the list to test it out.  Or

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked perfectly 
**HTML**

```
<ul id="top-list">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#top-list{
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;}
```

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else.

Because:

```
   ul#otis {
     list-style-type: none;
   }
```

should just work.

Perhaps there is some CSS rule which overwrites it.

Use your DOM inspector to find out.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and the way I ended up fixing it was like this:

```
ul, li{
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Maybe it's a little extreme, but when I did that, it worked for me.

---

Hope this helped

Answer (score 3):

for inline style sheet try this code

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>Try This</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

In a chrome, you can use

```
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
ul#otis {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

my suggestion:

```
#otis {
    list-style-type: none;

}
```

in css you need only use the `#id` not `element#id`. more helpful hints are provided here:
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem.

The solution was that the bullet was added via a **background image**, NOT via list-style-type. A quick 'background: none' and Bob's your uncle!