# how to remove the bullet point of this code using css

Tags: css

I want to remove the bullet point for this code. tried many ways but no luck. any help?

```
<div class="widget wpcw-widgets wpcw-widget-contact">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-label">Name</li>
        <li class="has-label">Address</li>
        <li class="has-label">Country</li>
        <li class="has-label">Address</li>
        <li class="has-label">Country</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need an unordered list without any bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027354/need-an-unordered-list-without-any-bullets)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting rid of bullet points from <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289805/getting-rid-of-bullet-points-from-ul)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.widget ul li{ list-style-type: none;}
```

```html
<div class="widget wpcw-widgets wpcw-widget-contact">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-label">Name</li>
        <li class="has-label">Address</li>
        <li class="has-label">Country</li>
        <li class="has-label">Address</li>
        <li class="has-label">Country</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the div container only list contact information, I'd recommend styling the elements using the `wpcw-widget-contact` class as it has a great fit with the context.

```css
.wpcw-widget-contact ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget wpcw-widgets wpcw-widget-contact">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-label">Name</li>
        <li class="has-label">Address</li>
        <li class="has-label">Country</li>
        <li class="has-label">Address</li>
        <li class="has-label">Country</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You also might be interested to look up more details [about the CSS property used on this answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style).