# Getting rid of a bullet for a single item

Tags: html, bulletedlist

I have a bullet list and I want *just a single item* without a bullet. How do I do that? For example, in the following, can I get the "Cheese" with no bullet:

```
<ol>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cheese</li>
  <li>Goats</li>
</ol>
```

Many good SO [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289805/getting-rid-of-bullet-points-from-ul#_=_) deal with changing the entire list, but I'm interested in a specific item.

Comment: Add a class to it and change the list item style so it does not have a bullet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just target any of the list items with class or pseudo selectors

Example below shows this using first-child and class

```css
li:first-child,
.no-bullet {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Milk </li>
  <li class="no-bullet">Cheese </li>
  <li>Goats </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be

```
ol > li:nth-child(2) {
   list-style: none;
}
```